# Array of Arrays for use in a For loop

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist

```
array<string, 7> month31={"January","March","May","July","August","October","December"};
array<string, 4> month30 ={"April","June","September","November"};
array<string, 1> month29 = {"February"};
array<string, 1> month28 = {"February"};
array<string, 4> months= {month31,month30,month29,month28};
```

I know in python this would work but it keeps crashing. Is there a syntax I am missing?
End goal is to use a for loop to move between the arrays, but if I can't figure that out in time I will have to hard code it all and that will be a pain.

Comment: I think you will need to add more details - like some code that uses your 'arrays'. But you'll likely be better off using `std::vector<string>` for your lists and then an `array` (or `vector`) of those: `array< vector<string>, 4 > months = { month31, month30, month29, month28 };`. (An `array` of `array` objects would require the element arrays to all be the same length.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely be better off using `std::vector<std::string>` for your (individual) month lists and then a `std::array< std::vector<string> >` for your composite (note that a `std::array` of `std::array<string, n>` would require the element arrays to all be the same length).

Here's a short, illustrative example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> month31 = { "January","March","May","July","August","October","December" };
    std::vector<std::string> month30 = { "April","June","September","November" };
    std::vector<std::string> month29 = { "February" };
    std::vector<std::string> month28 = { "February" };
    // The composite list can be a container of the above vector types ...
    std::array< std::vector<std::string>, 4 > months = { month31, month30, month29, month28 };

    for (auto& vec : months) { // Take REFERENCES (&) to avoid copying.
        std::cout << "--- Next List... ---" << std::endl;
        for (auto& month : vec) {
            std::cout << month << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you could also use `std::vector` for the composite; with all other lines in the above code unchanged, just use this for the declaration of `months`:

```cpp
   std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > months = { month31, month30, month29, month28 };
```

The (main) difference between `vector` and `array` is that, for `array`, the size, which is **fixed** at compile time and specified as a [template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), is also part of the actual **type** of the object. So, for your 4 components of different lengths, defining each as a `std::array` would make them types of 4 (or 3, actually) *different* classes (so they would not be suitable as members of a 'composite' `array` / `vector` container).

Answer (score 0):

You declared **months** as an array of (four) strings, but you want to initialize it with arrays (of strings) - the types don't match. What's more, you want to keep all those arrays in one, while they are all different sizes. Even with *auto* it wouldn't work.

What you can do is use *vector*, like:

```
vector<string> month31 = {"January","March","May","July","August","October","December"};
vector<string> month30 ={"April","June","September","November"};
vector<string> month29 = {"February"};
vector<string> month28 = {"February"};
vector<vector<string>> months= {month31,month30,month29,month28};
```